# No reputation gained for an answer on a migrated question

Tags: support, reputation, migration, voting

I answered a question posted on SO that was [later moved to Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/42530/what-is-directory).

I got 12 votes from the answer, but the rep was not added to my SO reputation. It wasn't added to my SU account either.

Why is that?

Do I have to connect the two (identical) accounts or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes. see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites

Comment: the link is broken by now.